# What is the meaning of として in this case?

Tags: grammar, meaning

> 同居している25歳の女性に暴行を加え殺害した**として,** 35歳の男、兔富士直樹容疑者が 殺人の疑いで逮捕されました (Death Note Ep 1)

In the above sentence, does として mean "to assume that", "to consider ~" or "to view ~ as ~"? But with these definitions, the sentence's meaning is rather weird. Please explain the using of として　in this case. Is it necessary to have the comma「、」 after として?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jisho has 'supposing that' as one of the definitions for とする. It appears to be linked with 逮捕されました. It is analogous to the following sentence from [Tangorin](http://tangorin.com/examples/%E3%81%A8%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%20%E9%80%AE%E6%8D%95).

> その男性はスパイとして逮捕された。
> The man was arrested as a spy.

The comma seems necessary because the sentence is broken up with another phrase that intervenes before 逮捕.

A 35-year-old male, 兔富士直, was arrested on suspicion of assaulting and murdering a 25-year-old female whom he cohabited with.

Answer (score 1):

My own personal fave TL would be:

> "on suspicion of"

While that might not look like a literal translation of 「～～として」, it certainly carries just about the same meaning and nuance.

The comma is optional, but it would be advizable to use one.