# 「verb + として」vs. 「noun + として」

Tags: particles

From the first episode of Death Note:

> 同居している25歳の女性に暴行を加え**殺害したとして**

Does the meaning of the particle として here, when it is placed after a verb, have the same meaning as when it is placed after a noun (i.e., "as")? Or does it have a [slightly] different meaning/usage in this context?

Comment: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/55302/30454

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4926/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11230/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/90189/9831 /